# How can I click a Dropdown menu option in a webpage using VB.NET and Selenium

Tags: vb.net, selenium, web, dropdown

I am trying to click on Supplier. I've added a screen shot of the source code. In this code sample I have successfully logged into the site, but the next step is to click on that dropdown to get to the next screen. I have hard coded the link and then used GET to call open the URL string. However, it's my understanding that I should be able to do this without hard coding the URL for Supplier. I should be able to pull it with a single line of code versus trying to figure out how to loop through somehow to get to the "Supplier" selection. I am trying to account for the scenario if this link changes so I want my code to pull it directly from the source vs hard coding. I've uploaded a screen shot of the source code. How can I click on supplier? [image: Screen Shot of Source Code]

```
   Dim ch As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
   Dim FindBy As New Selenium.By
   
   ch.Get("URL", raise:=False)
   ch.SwitchToFrame("MainFrame")

   ch.FindElementById("ctl04_txtUsername").SendKeys(Form1.TxtBId.Text)
   ch.FindElementById("ctl04_txtPassword").SendKeys(Form1.TxtBPass.Text)

   ch.FindElementById("ctl04_btnLogin").ClickDouble

   str = "https://am.adech.net/csge/portals/postmodern/desktpdefault.aspx?tabindex=1&tabid=211&sTarget=S"

   ch.Get str, Raise:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is:

First find the element by ID, find that elements anchor by tag, next getattribute by "href" and then navigate to that anchors "href" link.